# How to specify different dateNF for different columns while exporting xlsx from json

Tags: javascript, sheetjs, xlsx-js

I have following data -

```
{billDate: "21-1-2021", createdDate: "20-2-2021", modifiedDate: "20-2-2022"}
...
]
```

I have converted date string to date js objects.

While exporting to sheet using method `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet` How can i specify different dateNF for diffrent columns.

For example for billDate i need - dd-mm-yyyy but for other two dates i need output as mm-dd-yyyy.

So far i have tried following two ways

```js
// 1 column config 
// OUTPUT: has no impact of dateNF
XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, {
columns: [{
  name: "billDate",
  key: "billDate",
  dateNF: "dd-mm-yyyy"
},
{
  name: "createdDate",
  key: "createdDate",
  dateNF: "mm-dd-yyyy"
}]
});


// 2 above configuration with header property
// OUTPUT: Adds 3 columns with data "[object Object]" for 3 columns then after 3 columns adds original data
XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, {
  header: [{
   name: "billDate",
   key: "billDate",
   dateNF: "dd-mm-yyyy"
  },{
    name: "createdDate",
    key: "createdDate",
    dateNF: "mm-dd-yyyy"
  }]
});
```